# onListItemClick is not called

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I'm using an extention of ListFragment to display some data on the screen. I try to handle list items clicks via onListItemClick function, but when I click on list element this function is not called. The list element even doesn't become blue when I click. Looks like it doesn't feel my clicks. Here is my code:

DataListFragment.java:

```
public class DataListFragment extends ListFragment {   
    private CustomArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    public void setAdapter(CustomArrayAdapter adapter) {
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setEmptyText("");
        mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // I want this function to be called
        Log.i("DataListFragment", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
```

single_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/train_info"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" 
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:freezesText="true">
    </TextView>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_info"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

(every item of my list is two textviews is one row)

And at last CustomArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FinalData> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<FinalData> data) {
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            for (FinalData appEntry : data) {
                add(appEntry);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        FinalData item = getItem(position);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setSelected(true);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setSelected(true);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setText(item.getFullData());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setText(item.getTimeData());

        return view;
    }
}
```

So, this code shows all the data I want in the way I want but doesn't feel my clicks. Items of the list even don't become blue when I touch them...

I just follow one of android developer guides. I have a function onListItemClick inside my fragment but it doesn't work. Why?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: You need to call [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Comment: Where should I write this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use
     itemclicklistener

and in that write

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Cast this value returned by the above statement into a String if it is a string that u used for your listview.

Hope it.helps you.

Comment: Where I should use itemclicklistener?

Comment: You should  first write to your listview like listview.setOnItemClickListener(this); so now your class should implements onItemClickListener and jus override the method by this interface in that class..this automatically happens in eclipse.by click   and so you get this method call onListItemClicked having few arguments...so thats it

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with my onItemClick inside Fragment.It should work but it doesn't

Comment: How to access this listview?

Comment: See override onItemClick method in your class and handle clicks there it works rather than ovrriding the onListItemClick